Is Job 26:7 perhaps describing a location on earth and not the earth as a whole?
Job 26:6-7 ESV
[6] Sheol is naked before God, and Abaddon has no covering. [7] He stretches out the north over the void and hangs the earth on nothing.
This is not a question about the shape of the earth, but I can't help but imagine the Hebrew conception of the earth and heavens when reading this. It makes more sense to me that way, especially reading the verses before and after. When I read the text I am understanding the word "north" and "earth" as the same. The words "void" and "nothing" as the same. "Stretches" and "hangs" is what God is doing to the earth.  Stretching something out over something is the same as hanging it over something. Is verse 7 actually describing a location on the earth or the earth as a whole? Verse 6 is describing Sheol. Sheol is under the earth correct? Most of this chapter seems to be describing all of creation: sheol, the earth, and the heavens. I see heaven described as having pillars. My other question is why do some people take "pillars of heaven" as figurative but "hanging the earth" as literal when they have a belief in heliocentrism? Are people calling something figurative simply based on their understanding of the world we are presented through men's science?
I don't want to discuss the shape of the earth but moreso what is the void, the north, the verbs "stretching" and "hanging" in light of both views of the earth and heavens. Namely heliocentric vs Hebrew cosmology with a "flat" earth and sheol or Abaddon under the earth and pillars supporting the earth and heavens. That is my understanding of it so far.

Is this a statement or a question?

I am asking how both views interpret verse 7. I personally don't see either view as describing the earth as a whole in light of the north and earth being synonymous. But I have a hard time understanding the heliocentric view saying it means the whole earth is hanging. Could the north just be a location on the earth?

Job 26:7 is in the form of poetry where the first part of the verse is restated in the second part of the same verse, and indicates that one becomes equal to or a simile / metaphor for the other.  It is describing the entire creation, and is much misunderstood.
Excerpts from my blog post "Is the Earth Hanging Upon Nothing?" here

“He stretcheth out the north over the empty place, and hangeth the earth upon nothing.” (KJV)

or in the Complete Jewish Bible (CJB)

“He stretches the north over chaos, and suspends the earth on nothing,”

and in Young’s Literal Translation (YLT),

“Stretching out the north over desolation, Hanging the earth upon nothing,“

So, desolation, chaos, and empty place are all translated for Strong’s Heb 8414, which is “tohu” meaning formlessness, confusion, unreality, emptiness.

“`Thou dost not make to thyself a graven image, or any likeness which [is] in the heavens above, or which [is] in the earth beneath, or which [is] in the waters under the earth.“ (Ex. 20:4, YLT)

As the people could not make graven images of anything they could not see, then the heavens were the sky above, or the air.  Earth beneath the sky (heavens) was the land, countries, regions, territories, people of the land, as opposed to the sky.  Then the waters under the earth must be just those of the seas and the oceans?

“To Him spreading the earth over the waters, For to the age [is] His kindness.“  (Psa. 136:6, YLT)

...the first half of Job 26:7 has “north” which is restated in the second half as “earth.”  The Hebrew word for north is Strong’s 6828, transliterated as “tsaphon” and means north, northside, northern, northward. (Biblehub)

“The earth was unformed and void, darkness was on the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God hovered over the surface of the water.” (Gen. 1:2, CJB)

Unformed and void, face of the deep, water.
I believe that all of the commentaries are approaching Job 26:7 from the wrong perspective.  They are forcing a taught concept from “science” upon God’s word and trying to make the teaching of men take precedence over God’s word.
It is always the case that God’s scriptures interprets His word.  The commentary on Job 26:7 from the Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges seems typical.
“It may be doubtful whether “the north” refers to the northern part of the earth or to the northern heavens. In favour of the latter reference is the fact that the expression “stretch out,” often said in regard to the heavens (e.g. ch. Job 9:8), is not elsewhere used with reference to the earth, and it is scarcely probable that “the earth” would be used as a parallel to “the north,” a part of the earth.” (Source: Biblehub)
That the commentaries have to explain away the usual use of poetical repetition as first the part, then the whole for “earth” in Job 26:7 they then can use this as a rationale for their further discussion on their learned “scientific” prejudices.  They have digressed from the usual poetical construct of restating or replacing the object from the first half as a different word in the second half.
In Job 26:7 the word “north” is not a part of the “earth” in the 2nd half as is supposed above; it is restated as “earth” in the 2nd half.  So, in Job 26:7 north equals earth.
Now we can look back at Gen. 1:2, and compare.  Before Noah’s flood, the land masses were centered and together (Gen. 10:25).  In the creation, God separated the land / earth from the waters, raising the land above the waters below.
This is confirmed in Psa. 136:6 where God says He spread the earth / land over the waters.
Confirmed again in Ex. 20:4 with the waters being under the earth.
The word “water” in both Ex. 20:4 and Psa. 136:6 is Strong’s 4325, “mayim.”  (Biblehub) Brown-Driver-Briggs (BDB) has definitions as 1a) a spring or well; (1b) a river, Nile; 1c) sea; 1d) flood; 1e) subterranean (esp Ex. 20:4); 1f) in clouds; 1g) rain; 1h) dew; 1i) primEval deep.  The second definition is with the use of proper names , and the third is special uses as “water of the feet” or urine; water of a dunghill, or water (which is) distress as in drunk imprisonment, etc.
But the figurative uses are defined at BDB #4. As poetry uses figurative words, then we need to consider these: 4a – of distress as in many waters, or deep waters, or water of gall; 4b – of outbursting force; 4c. of rushing nations (Isa. 17:12); 4d – impetuous, violent, overwhelming as in Isa. 28:2, 17; Hos. 10:7; Job 27:20, etc; 4e – as running away such as of heart in timidity; or of the knees; 4f – transitoriness; 4g – refreshment; 4h – a figure of rest and peace; 4i – reckless bloodshed; 4j – figurative of bride, or enjoyment of one’s wife; 4k – of outpoured wrath; 4l abundant justice or outpoured feelings.
BDB 4a of distress as in many waters might be considered chaos.  BDB 4b of outbursting force, and 4c of rushing nations and 4d of violent, overwhelming all result in desolation.
Consider also the figurative use at BDB 4e of timid hearts and weak knees.  Weak knees are folding, unable to hold up, or to stand.  Timid hearts are also weak, unable to hold a position or to do what is necessary because they lack conviction and strength.  Not having strength to do, or to stand is baseless, or standing on nothing.
We cannot stand on water (that is, without Jesus’ help).
Strong’s Concordance also lists uses of “mayim” as waste, wasting, watering, and course.  So, water(s) = waste = emptiness = void, without form= nothing.
The Hebrew word for nothing is Strong’s 1099 transliterated as “belimah.” It is only used in Job 26:7. (Biblehub) There is no other use of this word in all of the OT.  That means the commentaries are speculating as they have no other Hebrew word to compare it with.
So, we have to compare the entirety of the verse with the rest of scripture.
Discarding taught “science” and learned biases, and basing our understanding only upon God’s word, based only upon the definitions and uses of His words, I believe it is very probable that the “nothing” of Job 26:7 is the formless, void, emptiness of Gen. 1:2, and of spreading the earth over the waters of Psa. 136:6.
So if we replace the poetry of Job 26:7 with the rest of scripture we find,
“Stretching out the [earth] over desolation, Hanging the earth upon [void, empty waters],”
is exactly the consistent poetic method of restating the first part in the second part, and is exactly what God said in Gen. 1:2 and Psa. 136:6.
With this analysis, God hung the earth over/upon the void, waste, desolate, chaotic waters of the deep.

“The earth is the Lord’s, and the fulness thereof; the world, and they that dwell therein. 2 For he hath founded it upon the seas, and established it upon the floods.” (Psa. 25:1-2, KJV)

Job 26:7 does not speak about just a part of the earth, but the whole creation, and indicates that the "nothing" it hangs on is the chaotic waters of Gen. 1.

Thank you. You sufficiently answered my questions. I will check out your blog for sure.

Ancient Mesopotamian cosmologies describe warring gods, dismemberment, and repurposed body parts in their creation stories. The earth is supported on the backs of large animals such as tortoises and elephants. One of the Greek Titans, Atlas, holds up the heavens. The sun and moon are powerful deities.
In contrast, the Bible contains no similar stories. But, according to the “stone-age goat-herders” who wrote Genesis, the sun and moon are simply luminaries—lamps, not gods, and the earth is not supported by any giant animals—it hangs on nothing (Job 26:7).
That the earth “hangs on nothing” is indeed what we believe today. But how can "the north" be stretched out? Well, modern theoretical physicists, beginning with Einstein, believe that gravity is not a force, but rather a deformation of the fabric of space-time. Of course, the Bible isn’t a science textbook and shouldn’t be used as one, but I’d not be quick to dismiss it on scientific grounds, especially considering that science is always changing while the Bible isn’t.
The famous medieval painting of a flat earth with a dome of the sky and stars, and heaven was NOT the cosmology of the ancient Hebrews, nor was it the cosmology of Egypt and other ancient civilizations.
For example, one ancient Egyptian painting illustrates the over-arching sky goddess (naked, of course) being held up from the reclining earth god by their god of light, dry air, and wind.
However, that the earth was spherical was known for centuries before Christ and is found in manuscripts from the 5th century BC. Even before then, it could easily be observed that ships disappeared over the horizon, but didn’t sink.
About 240 BC, Eratosthenes of Cyrene (located in modern day Libya) famously calculated the circumference of the spherical earth as 24,854 miles. He did this by assuming the rays of the sun were essentially parallel due to its large distance from the earth and then comparing the angles of the rays using shadows in two cities about 500 miles apart in Egypt at noon on the same day. The current computation of the circumference of the earth is 24,901 miles at the equator. Thus, Eratosthenes’ calculation was off by only about 47 miles, which is an accuracy within two tenths of one percent!
Notice that this is hardly a “flat earth” with a dome over it as depicted in Medieval paintings and unfairly projected by some scholars onto the ancient Greeks, the ancient Phoenician seafaring navigators, and perhaps in the writings of this godly sage, who most likely lived sometime between 2000 and 1000 BC in Uz, likely located in northwestern Arabia.

So I took the cup from the Lord's hand, and made all the nations to
whom the Lord sent me drink it: Jerusalem and the cities of Judah, its
kings and officials, to make them a desolation and a waste, a hissing
and a curse, as at this day; Pharaoh king of Egypt, his servants, his
officials, all his people, and all the mixed tribes among them; all
the kings of the land of Uz and all the kings of the land of the
Philistines (Ashkelon, Gaza, Ekron, and the remnant of Ashdod); Edom,
Moab, and the sons of Ammon; all the kings of Tyre, all the kings of
Sidon, and the kings of the coastland across the sea; Dedan, Tema,
Buz, and all who cut the corners of their hair; all the kings of
Arabia and all the kings of the mixed tribes who dwell in the desert;
all the kings of Zimri, all the kings of Elam, and all the kings of
Media; all the kings of the north, far and near, one after another,
and all the kingdoms of the world that are on the face of the earth.
And after them the king of Babylon shall drink. – Jeremiah 25:17-26
ESV

Hope this helps.

A scientist who is Professor of Physics at Durham University and an expert on molecular theory of complex fluid flow, has written about that verse in Job, as it relates to the creation account. First, he quotes the passage:

“He it is who stretched out the North over chaos, and suspended the
Earth from nothing. He wrapped up the waters in his clouds, but the
clouds did not burst under their weight.” Job 26:7
“This is clearly another creation story; as much a description of the
creative act as it is of the current and resultant structure of the
universe. The ‘North’ here is a little puzzling, as it is clearly not
simply the geographical direction but is more appropriate to the
dynamics of construction of the heavenly fabric itself – perhaps
stretched out from south to north. Astonishing suspension is
everywhere – clouds hang, freighted with tons of water but without
support; the heavenly vault is likewise without a central pillar, and
the Earth itself at the centre hangs from nothing at all.
Metaphorically we even catch a beautiful sight of the idea of order
‘suspended’ over the sea of chaos. But the beauty once glimpsed is
shattered by the terror of it all. In a reference unique in the Bible to the 'pillars of heaven' we find fear even there (26:11)" Faith & Wisdom in Science, Tom McLeish, page 129 (Oxford University Press 2014)

"The pillars of heaven trembled; they were aghast at his rebuke" - Job 25:11, then he goes on into that.
Context shows that the ‘hanging of the Earth on nothing’ is a parallel
with the clouds appearing to hang on nothing, despite their massive
weight. It is an awesome contemplation. How could the wealthy
businessman who made that observation possibly know that Earth was
‘floating’ in space?"
Earlier on in his book, McLeish flags up the foolishness of those who would pitch science against religious faith (and vice versa). This is not directly related to the question except insofar as it serves to break down unnecessary barriers to understanding - on both sides.

"The battle between Religion and Science only arises when people don't
distinguish between theory / theology, and practice.
We need to treat those two disciplines as distinct in their remit and
capabilities (for Science can say nothing about that which is
immaterial). It's only when Scientists and supporters of scientism
start spouting on about metaphysics that the clash arises on their
side. And it's only when Religionists swallow the bait, wrongly
supposing that Scientific theories are some kind of threat to their
beliefs about God that the clash arises on their side." (Ibid. page
17)

Wise words. He takes 268 pages to delve deeply into this oft-times poetic book of Job, so I can only take a very small part of it, to show you the need to view this wonderful book of the Bible as being full of ancient wisdom, especially the divine wisdom of God when he rebukes his critics at the end.
EDIT re. verse 6. The reference to sheol is about the condition of the dead. The dead are out of sight. Yet millions have never been buried under the earth. Consider those who died at sea and were eaten by sea creatures. Consider how Jonah, when in the belly of the great fish, said, "Out of the belly of hell cried I", the Hebrew word sheol having been translated into English as 'hell'. Millions more have been atomised into the air in recent generations, by explosions - again, they were never laid in earth. So, verse 6 should not have a bearing on verse 7 as regards any location. The answer to your question is simply, "No, this is not about any one location."
